# I am facing issue with Nil Coalescing in Swift

Tags: swift, null-coalescing-operator

Is there a way of not using forced unwrapping in the nil coalescing operator, in Swift?

I tried using:

```
Int(errorCodeString?) ?? 500
```

But, this didn't work.

The overall code snippet is:

```
var errorCodeString: String?

errorCodeString = "404"

let actualErrorCode = Int(errorCodeString!) ?? 500

print("Actual Error Code: \(actualErrorCode)")
```

Comment: What error are you facing? Your code is working fine for me!

Comment: instead of forced unwrapping "errorCodeString", if you use Int(errorCodeString?) ?? 500 , you will see the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  Use the `nil coalescing operator` twice, once to unwrap the `String?` and the second time to unwrap the `Int?`:

```
let actualErrorCode = Int(errorCodeString ?? "") ?? 500
```

---

#### Explanation:

Your `errorCodeString` is an optional `String` (aka `String?`).  Performing `errorCodeString ?? ""` will either unwrap `errorCodeString` if it is not `nil` or replace it with `""` if it is `nil`.

The result of that is passed to the `Int` initializer which takes a `String`.  The `Int(_:String)` initializer turns that `String` into an `Int?` which either contains the integer value or `nil` if the `String` doesn't represent a valid `Int`.  The second nil coalescing operator `??` unwraps that `Int?` or replaces it with `500` if the value is `nil`.

What you tried initially `Int(errorCodeString?) ?? 500` doesn't work because following an optional with `?` only conditionally unwraps it in an *optional chain*.  In that case, you must follow the `?` with a member access, method call, or indexing operator `[]`.

Comment: Yeah, this works.  Can you explain what is happening here?

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful explanation.
But, here if errorCodeString is nil, its value is changed to "". What if I don't wanna change errorCodeString if its nil, say I want it to remain nil?

Comment: okay, I tried to check errorCodeString's value, it still says nil, that is what I wanted.
Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `Int` initializer does not accept a optional.

Your `Int(errorCodeString?) ?? 500` is syntactically incorrect. Use `Int(errorCodeString ?? "") ?? 500` instead.

Comment: What you suggested, works fine. Can you explain further.

Comment: When searching for a way to work with Int32 core data attributes for item quantity I was running into a nil coalescing issue in a ForEach (SwiftUI) that was previously only using strings. A simple modification like this worked like a charm. 

quantity: Int(currentItem.itemQuantity)